# Elasticsearch plugin to modify the source document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to write a custom plugin for elasticsearch where I can modify some fields of my source document and after modification I should be able to index the modified document.

Any help will be appreciated!!!!

Comment: You can use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) for this purpose. Logstash already has lots of plugins that you can use for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Look at ingest plugin eco system -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest.html

For example - [this](https://github.com/johtani/elasticsearch-ingest-csv) deals with CSV